# on integral equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the equation 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(\omega\tau)f(\tau)d\tau =\omega\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\omega\tau)f(\tau)d\tau\;,
$$
where $\omega >0$ and $f$ is a probability density function. I would like to know whether this equation always has solutions $\omega$.

Comment: My wild guess is yes, by the following reasoning: the left-hand side is always between $-1$ and $1$, while the right-hand side has that growing factor of $\omega$, so might well take both values greater than $1$ and values less than $-1$. (Note that both integrals tend to $0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, if that is helpful at all.)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would begin the hunt for a counterexample by observing that, if $f$ is $C^1$, then the equation can be rewritten $$\int_0^\infty \sin (\omega \tau) \left( f+f'\right)\, d\tau=0. $$

Comment: So we should look for a function $f$ such that the Fourier sine transform of $f+f'$ never vanishes.

Answer (score 5):

Following @GiuseppeNegro's hint, if $f$ is the PDF of the exponential distribution with parameter $a$, one asks for solutions $\omega$ of the equation
$$
\int_0^\infty\sin(\omega\tau)(a-1)\mathrm e^{-a\tau}\mathrm d\tau=0.
$$
Writing this as the imaginary part of the integral of $\tau\mapsto(a-1)\exp((\mathrm i \omega-a)\tau)$, one gets the condition
$$
\Im\left(\frac{a-1}{a-\mathrm i \omega}\right)=0=\frac{(a-1)\omega}{a^2+\omega^2},
$$
which, if $a\ne1$, has no solution $\omega\ne0$.